# How to replace the \n characters in the body section of an html with <br>

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I am getting an html into a string which contains a bunch of \n characters.

```
  "<html>\n  <head>\n    <style type=\"text/css\">\n      <!--\n        p { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0 }\n      -->\n    </style>\n    \n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <p>\n      <b><font face=\"Arial\" size=\"4\"><i>Hello.....\n</i></font></b>    </p>\n    <p>\n  <b><font face=\"Arial\" size=\"4\"><i>Thanks, </i></font></b>\n    </p>\n    <p>\n      <b><i><font face=\"Arial\" size=\"4\">XXXX</font></i></b>\n    </p>\n  </body>\n</html>\n"
```

I want to replace all the \n characters in the body section of that html with a break tag. for that I am using the following regex.

```
str.replaceAll("(?<!>)\n", "<br>"));
```

So this is replacing all the `'\n'` characters that are not preceded by a >. But in the string, there is something like `!--\n` in the head section of the html which is getting replaced as well. I want the replace to be done only for the \n characters in the body part of the html. Can this be done?.

If not regex, Can someone give me an idea of how I should be parsing for the body tag in the string and then replace the \n characters in that part using the regex.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to split the string to get separately the head content and the body content and then replace all `\n` occurences within this last one, here's what you should do:

```js
var str = "<html>\n  <head>\n    <style type=\"text/css\">\n      <!--\n        p { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0 }\n      -->\n    </style>\n    \n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <p>\n      <b><font face=\"Arial\" size=\"4\"><i>Hello.....\n</i></font></b>    </p>\n    <p>\n  <b><font face=\"Arial\" size=\"4\"><i>Thanks, </i></font></b>\n    </p>\n    <p>\n      <b><i><font face=\"Arial\" size=\"4\">XXXX</font></i></b>\n    </p>\n  </body>\n</html>\n";

function replaceNewLine(string) {

  if (str.indexOf("<body>") > 0) {
    var index = str.indexOf("<body>");
    var heading = str.substring(0, index);
    var content = str.substring(index);
    return heading + content.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
  }

}
alert(replaceNewLine(str));
```

- You will use `.indexOf()` and `.substring()` functions to get the
  body section.
- And then you will use the Regex with `replace()` function to replace `\n` occurences.